# GetProcessDpiAwareness() prior to Windows 8

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, dpi, dpi-aware

I know that I can use `GetProcessDpiAwareness()` to check the dpi awareness of a particular process. However this is only supported from Windows 8.1 upwards. Is there any way to query the dpi awareness of a process prior to that?
I couldn't find any information about it.

Particularly I want to know if the process was ran with `[x] Disable display scaling on high DPI settings` (which was available at least from Windows 7.

Comment: There is [`IsProcessDPIAware()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isprocessdpiaware), available since Windows Vista, but it only works for the current process.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking for a method that works for other processes as well, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you check the "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" checkbox on Windows 7 (and 8) that setting is [stored in the registry](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/11/21/disabling-dpi-scaling-on-windows-8-1-the-enterprise-way/), by creating a key the name of which is the fully qualified path to the executable under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` and the content of which is:

- `HIGHDPIAWARE` to enable display scaling
- `~ HIGHDPIAWARE` to explicitly disable display scaling

So you could simply look up that registry key to see whether display scaling was enabled or disabled for the process.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.